# Official ESTA application website and are the others scams?

Tags: online-resources, esta, applications, scams

A quick search for ESTA application returned many results. According to [this page on cbp.gov](http://www.cbp.gov/travel/international-visitors/esta), the official site to apply for an ESTA is [esta.cbp.dhs.gov](https://esta.cbp.dhs.gov/).

Are the others scams, legitimate third party resellers or "added value" services?

- http://www.applyesta.com/ (defunct - domain is for sale circa 2020)
- http://www.esta.us/
- https://www.esta.ie/

Can anyone confirm either way?

*Updated 2020*: The above have better "not affiliated with the U.S. Government" warnings now, but beware there are newer more sneaky sites starting all the time:

- https://www.official-esta.com/
- https://www.application-esta.co.uk/
- https://estaoficial.website/

And fortunately more official guidance about this issue: https://nz.usembassy.gov/be-aware-of-esta-scams/

Comment: Any value that may be added is so minimal as to be negligible.

Comment: Also see "Will getting a refund from an ESTA scam site cause me to be blacklisted from the US?" https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/54038/32207

Comment: From the sites that you've given, the first one now links to the official application site. The others charge an $88 fee, instead of the $14, for "professional review". Which in the best case this means means "we collect the exact same information than the official form, and submit it to the government for just $74". Don't fall for it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[It is legal](http://canberra.usembassy.gov/esta_scam.html) for a third party web site to accept an ESTA application from you and submit it on your behalf.

However, [you may be charged more than the statutory $14](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1164/~/esta--ive-been-charged-more-than-$14.00-for-esta,-why%3F) you would be charged at the official page. You may also have visited [a fake web site](http://www.theguardian.com/money/2015/jun/06/copycat-esta-websites-us-visitors), and there is no good way to determine in advance if the site will really submit the application for you or not.

It's best, then, to always go to the [official ESTA web site](https://esta.cbp.dhs.gov/) to apply or update your information. Note that virtually all U.S. government web sites have a domain ending in `.gov`.

Of course, it is *illegal* under US law for a site to take your money and *not* submit the ESTA application. CBP recommends that, if this has happened to you, that you dispute the charges with your bank or credit card issuer.