I formally gave up my green card 7 months ago. How long do I wait before I apply for an ESTA?
I was granted a Green Card during 2020 lockdown. I had to fly to the USA as soon as possible to activate it. I mistakenly thought I needed to also apply for an ESTA, which was denied as I was a Green Card holder (LPR). I then entered the US with my Green Card.
I decided that I no longer wanted the Green Card and wanted to return to live in the UK as I missed my boyfriend. I formally gave up my Green Card 7 months ago.
I would like to be able to apply for an ESTA as I would like to now visit my mother, an American citizen, who has Parkinson's Disease and not very well.
I have the paperwork that shows that I gave up the Green Card.
I am not sure how long I need to wait before I can apply for an ESTA online. I am worried that I mistakenly tried to apply for an ESTA and was denied because they already saw me as a Permanent Resident. Will my ESTA be denied due to a stupid error on my part? What would be recommended I do in this case?
NEW UPDATE - I applied for an ESTA and was denied. It said that I may be able to apply for a tourist visa, which will end up costing over $1,000 (an ESTA is $21) for all costs involved. I could still be denied. What will be hard is explaining to mom I can't come.
I have no desire to live in the US at all, which is why I chose to not take it up. At least the UK is not as harsh as the US, as she could visit me, but it is her health that is an issue and she cannot travel alone.

My mother married an American citizen 25 years ago. She was a British citizen. Gave it up for American Cit. My father is British and also remarried and lives in England as I do.

Aside: given your mother is a US citizen, are you sure you are not one yourself?

This is a very important comment to address.

@jcaron: The US consualte almost certainly would have investigated that and determined that the OP was not a US citizen, before they issued the OP an immigrant visa.

@user102008 Maybe they made a mistake.  That would hardly be unusual.

The mother might have become a US citizen after the daughter reached the age of majority.

@Marianne013 There are quite a few more cases when people do not automatically acquire US citizenship from their parents, so I’m definitely not saying that OP is necessarily a US citizen just because their mother is, but some cases are a bit complex and it could have been overlooked.

My mother married an American Citizen 25 years ago, she was a British Citizen but gave it up. My parents divorced 30 years ago. My mother dreamed of me joining her and living in the US. I never lived in the US, only had gone on holiday once a year for a week. It took 9 years for my family Green Card as I am British and less family visas are approved from wealthy countries. Ones life changes over 9 years. I tried to live in the US but could not as I missed my life and relationship in the UK. I would like to visit my mother who is 76 and I am 56 .

Thanks for all your answers much appreciated

"It said that I may be able to apply for a tourist visa, which will end up costing over $1,000": a tourist visa is $185 (and will be valid for 10 years and allow you to stay for longer than 90 days at a time).  What accounts for the other more-than-$815 cost of obtaining the visa? Do you live far from the consulate?

You should be able to apply for an ESTA now.
If ever the application is denied, the alternative route is to apply for a B-1/B-2 visa, but depending where you are based, this may take a much longer time.
Note that having had a green card previously and having family in the US may make proving non-immigrant intent quite a bit more difficult. You would need to be able to establish proof of strong ties to your home country.

If she gave up green card willingly, why would they think immigration would be the intent? If she wanted to live there, she wouldn't have given up greed card, no?

@akostadinov People change their minds, as clearly evidenced here. "I want to immigrate to the US". "Oh no finally I don't want to" could be followed by "Oh I changed my mind again maybe I want". I'm not saying they will think immigration is the intent, just that they may wonder about it.

Is there some kind of other visa she can get then? I mean wanting to visit a mother with parkinson's seems like a really good reason to go. Any chance there's a humanitarian argument?

@DRF for now the quick route is to ask for an ESTA.

My mother married an american citizen 25 years ago. She was a British Citizen. Gave it up for American Cit. My father is British and also remarried and lives in England as I do.

@jcaron My understanding is that if you are ever denied an ESTA for any reason, you become forever ineligible to apply for one: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/54038/will-getting-a-refund-from-an-esta-scam-site-cause-me-to-be-blacklisted-from-the

@lambshaanxy not sure exactly which part of that question or answer you refer to, but it says “may” be denied. And the official ESTA site clearly states that you can reapply after having been denied (but that if the circumstances haven’t changed you are likely to be denied again). There are a few circumstances like a previous overstay or being turned away at the border which make you ineligible, but apparently not being just denied an ESTA (especially in this case, I suppose).

@DebDavies did your mother actually renounce her British citizenship?  If so, she did not have to.  If she didn't formally apply for and receive a "declaration of renunciation" from the UK government then she is still a British citizen.

@lambshaanxy "My understanding is that if you are ever denied an ESTA for any reason, you become forever ineligible to apply for one": that is not correct.

I also gave up my Green Card a few years ago and moved back to London (my wife is American) we then moved back to America a few years later, this time I went in on an O1 Visa through work, I then left that job and we moved back to the UK again.
I haven't been back since however we wanted to this Christmas so my wife can see her family, I applied for an ESTA to check (last time I tried it was denied) but this time it was accepted.
So I'm assuming so long as enough time has passed it works. I obviously haven't attempted to enter the country yet so don't know what I am going to be faced with but I have an ESTA so can't see what the problem would be, same as you I have no intention in living there, if I did I would of stayed the previous times or would of applied for something else with my wife being American (she has a UK visa and our kids have both UK and American passports).

Can you please add how long it was between giving up the green card and getting the ESTA?
