# Travelling from UK to US. Never flown before, need a checklist!

Tags: usa, passports, international-travel, esta, uk-citizens

I'm a British citizen planning to travel from London Heathrow to Miami within the next couple of months. I'm in the process of applying for a passport, but I've also read a bunch of other confusing and sometimes conflicting information and could do with someone clearing it up for me.

- ESTA/VWP: I read that you need a biometric passport to qualify for this, do I need to do anything besides get a passport (and then apply for ESTA obviously)?
- API: What do I need to do for this?
- Customs: I'm going for a two-week trip and will be staying with a friend. How much money will customs expect me to have? How do I prove that I have funds besides carrying cash?

So I know I need a passport, flight tickets, funds, travel insurance, and need to apply for ESTA and do something with API (couldn't find any clear info on that). Is there anything I've missed that I need to be aware of?

Comment: API: it's the airline's responsibility. Just give then whatever information they ask for when they ask for it.  Funds: if you're worried about this, bring some bank statements (and a bank card, of course).  Passport: I am pretty sure that all new UK passports are biometric.

Comment: Hi and welcome. Imho this is kinda broad as it stands. I think you should split your question: the ESTA and API queries can fit into one post. The part about proof of funds and accomodation should be asked separately. Please search the site before asking.

Comment: @JoErNanO Given that ESTA is such a well-known thing, surely any basic question about it is either a duplicate or is answered fully on the Department of Homeland Security website.

Comment: @DavidRicherby sure but this might be a great opportunity to create a canonical QA.

Comment: No customs agent in the US has ever asked me for funds I have, and I travel in and out several times ayear, for more than ten years. Either way, my answer would be that I have a credit card, period. I don't think this is a real requirement.

Answer (score 2):

If you've applied for a passport in 2016, you'll already receive a biometric passport, so you do not need to be concerned about that. This will be evidenced by the symbol at the bottom of the front cover.

[image: UK passport front cover]
Source: [gov.uk](https://assets.digital.cabinet-office.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/image_data/file/23709/s300_british_passport.jpg)

After you get your passport, you can apply for the ESTA. Be sure you only go to [the official ESTA web site](https://esta.cbp.dhs.gov/) as there are [fake ESTA web sites](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/52406/3221) around. You should be charged exactly $14 USD; if you see a larger number than this, you are on a third party web site.

You don't need to worry about APIS. This is handled by your airline. After you book your tickets, the airline will submit your details to the US to verify your clearance to enter the country. This happens behind the scenes and as long as you've given the airline your correct passport number, and your ESTA is approved, it should go fine.

As for how much money you need, you only need to:

- Make sure you have enough money to afford your holiday.

  This amount will vary depending on what you plan to do. But you will need to pay for accommodations, food, travel, tourist attractions, souvenirs.

  When the [CBP](http://www.cbp.gov/) officer asks how much money you have, state *both* how much cash you have on hand, *and* how much you have access to in your bank accounts.

  The CBP officer will not be looking for a specific amount of money. Rather, he will be looking to find out whether you have actually put thought into how much money you need. You should be able to describe your plans and the expenses you expect. A printout of your current bank balance can be helpful as you might be asked to prove that you have access to the money.

  As for cash, you don't need to bring any cash, as long as you have debit or credit cards that work in the US. Contact your bank(s) before you leave the UK to advise them of your holiday and ensure that your cards will work in the US. However, you *should* obtain some cash, because while plastic is almost universally accepted in the US, *foreign* credit cards don't work in a few (largely unpredictable) places. Also, don't be surprised when you insert your card into a chip reader and are told that the reader doesn't work and to swipe the magnetic stripe instead.
- Make sure you have return air tickets.

Finally, on your *first* visit to the US, you must see an immigration officer, then after you're cleared, claim your baggage, and see a customs officer. [On *future* visits you can use Automated Passport Control kiosks for immigration clearance](http://www.cbp.gov/travel/us-citizens/automated-passport-control-apc) and go directly to baggage claim and customs.

Comment: Are you sure about visitors being able to use the automated kiosks? I thought they were only for US citizens (and possibly foreigners who've registered to use them). I've travelled to the US multiple times and arrived at multiple airports and the signs always just direct non-citizens into the big queue to talk to an immigration officer.

Comment: @David may depend on the airport, I have certainly used the kiosks (uk passport, esta, not first visit)

Comment: @DavidRicherby The airport terminal you arrive in has to _have_ the kiosks to begin with. This is a different program to Global Entry, and it is relatively new. Aside from that, it works exactly as described. I suspect you've been waiting in the queue many times when you didn't really need to.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I'm surprised they don't make it more obvious. But, thinking about it, since I've only had a biometric passport for the last twelve months, it's unlikely that I'd have been able to use any such kiosk even if I'd noticed it.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Next visit, look for the Automated Passport Control signs, and breeze right through.