# Is this a legit ESTA application?

Tags: usa, money, esta, us-visa-waiver-program, fraud

I filled an ESTA application. Two days later I received the following email from `info@estausa.org`

> Dear John Doe,
>
> We kindly ask you to reconfirm your Gender – Male or Female?
>
> Before we can finish processing your application, we kindly ask you to reconfirm your Passport Issuance Date, Expiration Date and Number.
>
> Please open your passport and confirm below.
>
> Passport Issuance Date:
>
> Day:
>
> Month:
>
> Year:
>
> Passport Expiration Date:
>
> Day:
>
> Month:
>
> Year:
>
> Passport Number: –
>
> We will process your application once we receive your response.
>
> Please let us know if you have any questions.
>
> Regards,
>
> Customer Service Team ESTA USA
>
> www.estausa.org info@estausa.org
>
> ---
>
> DISCLAIMER: This domain and website is operated by a private company not affiliated with any government agencies, consulates or embassies.
>
> CONFIDENTIALITY NOTICE: Email communication is intended to be viewed only by the listed recipient(s). It may contain information that is privileged and confidential. Any dissemination, distribution or copying of this message is strictly prohibited without our prior written permission. If you are not an intended recipient, or if you have received this communication in error, please notify us immediately by return e-mail.

This email (and email address) feels very weird to me. I quickly found [this post](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/52406/official-esta-application-website-and-are-the-others-scams) stating that there are fraud websites. Scrolling through my history, I realized that I used the website http://www.esta.us/ and not https://esta.cbp.dhs.gov/esta/. I seem to be the victim of a fraud.

I do not quite remember if I paid and what I paid when applying for this ESTA but I guess I paid something. I failed to see any payment on my personal bank account (via my bank website) though.

Am I the victim of a fraud (or legal but unreasonably expensive service)? What would you advise me to go from here?

Comment: The answer to "is this legit" is very much in the email itself:

```DISCLAIMER: This domain and website is operated by a private company not affiliated with any government agencies, consulates or embassies.```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Thankfully your card hasn't been charged. **Do not continue to deal with this service**

**ONLY** use [the government site](https://esta.cbp.dhs.gov/esta/), **NOTHING** else. Not only are you likely to be charged much more; they may not even submit the application correctly, which could have devastating immigration-related legal consequences for you.

Comment: To add to this, they should also immediately cancel/replace the card as the fraudsters could potentially take the amount at any time (the OP said that they can't see any charge on their bank statement so it's safe to assume that the card details have been stored somewhere in plaintext and are extremely vulnerable).

Comment: @cybermonkey If criminals have your card number, then whether they store it encrypted or not is the least of your concerns.

Comment: In general, don't give an online merchant your actual real credit card number, generate a virtual CC number with a date and spend limit. This applies particular to once-off transactions with vendors of unknown trustworthiness, or in foreign countries.

Comment: @smci Can you link to a resource explaining how it's possible to do that? I've never heard of any service allowing private individuals to create these virtual credit card numbers.

Comment: @DavidZ Look up Virtual Credit Card on Google, there's a few providers that let you do this. EntroPay is one such company. Note that they charge relatively hefty fees so I wouldn't use it everywhere...

Comment: Eh, one time CC numbers are everywhere in the EU, North America is decades behind in credit card services but even there for example https://www.cardbenefits.citi.com/Products/Virtual-Account-Numbers and https://www.bankofamerica.com/privacy/accounts-cards/shopsafe.go

Comment: Yes, I was saying your bank, not a third-party. In the US, Citibank and BoA do VCC numbers.

Comment: By the way, the [US government-looking seal in the top-left of ESTA.us's webpage](http://www.esta.us/images/estaus-logo.gif) makes them reportable to the FBI for pretending to be a govt agency (note tiny disclaimer at bottom of screen). Report them now: https://www.ic3.gov/crimeschemes.aspx

Comment: @immibis My point is that if they stored it encrypted (some payment solutions do that, via a hash from the payment processor, without taking any money from the card), only *they* would be able to use it. If they stored it in plaintext, then they could easily sell-on the information and cause many more issues for the victim.

Comment: @cybermonkey Scammers use legitimate payment processors instead of a phishing page?

Comment: @immibis Some of them do (namely the quick 'pop-up' ones that disappear quickly), surprisingly.

Comment: The official ESTA site lists a fee of $14. The $37 fee from this scam site is more than 2.5x that. Also, there are numerous scams like this for official forms and services, some of which are even *free* from the official source!

Comment: @GalacticCowboy Not least for permanent residence (green card) applications

Answer (score 14):

To add to the other answer, <strike>of course it is fake</strike> (edit: see jpatokal's comment) this company may not be fake, but I would immediately cancel all business with them. They *seem* to act as an unneccessary (hence too expensive) intermediary, but a lot of things they do indicate either an unreliable company or a scam. There are just too many red flags:

1. You visited domain esta.us and received mail from estausa.org.
2. Read their [terms and conditions](http://www.esta.us/terms.html):

> ESTA.us specializes in the Visa Waiver Program and Electronic System for Travel Authorization (ESTA)

*specializes in* instead of *handles*

> ESTA.us cannot warrant the information. ESTA.us provides the text on this website for information purposes only.

So much for guarantees....

> The Application Guide offered for sale on this website ....

So that is what they (also) do: they sell some info.
That does not necessarily exclude that they would handle ESTA applications, but then why don't they say anything about that?

3. And then this one from the [privacy policy](http://www.esta.us/privacy.html) is a gem:

> ESTA.us uses servers located in the United Kingdom.

Sure, for a supposedly US service/company...

4. There is much more on the site to show you you should be suspicious. They actually say that they just want your money [on this page](https://www.estausa.com/en/esta-us/verify-update.html):

> We specialize in processing, updating and verification of eVisa applications on behalf of travelers. We charge a processing fee of $ 37.00 per application. It is optional to use our professional service, and you have the choice of reviewing your own application without our help directly with the government at: https://esta.cbp.dhs.gov.

5. And did you notice that *that* page is suddenly on another domain (estausa.com), even with different terms and conditions? 
   This is almost a joke.

Comment: And *DISCLAIMER: This domain and website is operated by a private company not affiliated with any government agencies, consulates or embassies.*

Comment: It's not "fake", because they'll get you an actual visa.  But it's a company proxying the requests and charging a steep, pointless fee for it.